# How do you use Sass to create hover button color?

Tags: button, sass, colors, bootstrap-5

I've tried using this code in my editor, but it's not working, I'm guessing it's used for older versions of bootstrap.

```
.button {
   &:hover {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
   }
}
```

I can change the button font color by using:

```
$btn-font-family: {value}
```

But I don't know how to change button color on hover. Please help me.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to change the Bootstrap button background color on hover.

### Option 1: Via CSS

Add the following CSS:

```
button.btn {
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: red;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
button.btn {
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Option 2: Via SASS variables

Those are all [SASS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/#sass-variables) for Bootstrap buttons:

```
$btn-color:                   var(--#{$prefix}body-color);
$btn-padding-y:               $input-btn-padding-y;
$btn-padding-x:               $input-btn-padding-x;
$btn-font-family:             $input-btn-font-family;
$btn-font-size:               $input-btn-font-size;
$btn-line-height:             $input-btn-line-height;
$btn-white-space:             null; // Set to `nowrap` to prevent text wrapping

$btn-padding-y-sm:            $input-btn-padding-y-sm;
$btn-padding-x-sm:            $input-btn-padding-x-sm;
$btn-font-size-sm:            $input-btn-font-size-sm;

$btn-padding-y-lg:            $input-btn-padding-y-lg;
$btn-padding-x-lg:            $input-btn-padding-x-lg;
$btn-font-size-lg:            $input-btn-font-size-lg;

$btn-border-width:            $input-btn-border-width;

$btn-font-weight:             $font-weight-normal;
$btn-box-shadow:              inset 0 1px 0 rgba($white, .15), 0 1px 1px rgba($black, .075);
$btn-focus-width:             $input-btn-focus-width;
$btn-focus-box-shadow:        $input-btn-focus-box-shadow;
$btn-disabled-opacity:        .65;
$btn-active-box-shadow:       inset 0 3px 5px rgba($black, .125);

$btn-link-color:              var(--#{$prefix}link-color);
$btn-link-hover-color:        var(--#{$prefix}link-hover-color);
$btn-link-disabled-color:     $gray-600;

// Allows for customizing button radius independently from global border radius
$btn-border-radius:           var(--#{$prefix}border-radius);
$btn-border-radius-sm:        var(--#{$prefix}border-radius-sm);
$btn-border-radius-lg:        var(--#{$prefix}border-radius-lg);

$btn-transition:              color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;

$btn-hover-bg-shade-amount:       15%;
$btn-hover-bg-tint-amount:        15%;
$btn-hover-border-shade-amount:   20%;
$btn-hover-border-tint-amount:    10%;
$btn-active-bg-shade-amount:      20%;
$btn-active-bg-tint-amount:       20%;
$btn-active-border-shade-amount:  25%;
$btn-active-border-tint-amount:   10%;
```

Those SASS variables are used in a [`button-variant`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/#sass-mixins) mixin (see `scss/mixins/_buttons.scss` file):

```
@mixin button-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast($background),
  $hover-background: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-shade-amount), tint-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-tint-amount)),
  $hover-border: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($border, $btn-hover-border-shade-amount), tint-color($border, $btn-hover-border-tint-amount)),
  $hover-color: color-contrast($hover-background),
  $active-background: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($background, $btn-active-bg-shade-amount), tint-color($background, $btn-active-bg-tint-amount)),
  $active-border: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($border, $btn-active-border-shade-amount), tint-color($border, $btn-active-border-tint-amount)),
  $active-color: color-contrast($active-background),
  $disabled-background: $background,
  $disabled-border: $border,
  $disabled-color: color-contrast($disabled-background)
) {
  --#{$prefix}btn-color: #{$color};
  --#{$prefix}btn-bg: #{$background};
  --#{$prefix}btn-border-color: #{$border};
  --#{$prefix}btn-hover-color: #{$hover-color};
  --#{$prefix}btn-hover-bg: #{$hover-background};
  --#{$prefix}btn-hover-border-color: #{$hover-border};
  --#{$prefix}btn-focus-shadow-rgb: #{to-rgb(mix($color, $border, 15%))};
  --#{$prefix}btn-active-color: #{$active-color};
  --#{$prefix}btn-active-bg: #{$active-background};
  --#{$prefix}btn-active-border-color: #{$active-border};
  --#{$prefix}btn-active-shadow: #{$btn-active-box-shadow};
  --#{$prefix}btn-disabled-color: #{$disabled-color};
  --#{$prefix}btn-disabled-bg: #{$disabled-background};
  --#{$prefix}btn-disabled-border-color: #{$disabled-border};
}
```

This is the line in the mixin you're interested in:

```
$hover-background: if($color == $color-contrast-light, shade-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-shade-amount), tint-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-tint-amount))
```

It's a conditional expression using the if function. The syntax for the if function is:

```
if(condition, value-if-true, value-if-false)
```

As you can see, Bootstrap first checks whether the variable `$color` is equal to the variable `$color-contrast-light`:

- If yes (i.e., `$color` is equal to `$color-contrast-light`), the value of `$hover-background` will be the result of the `shade-color` function with the parameters `$background` and `$btn-hover-bg-shade-amount`.
- If no (i.e., `$color` is not equal to `$color-contrast-light`), the value of `$hover-background` will be the result of the `tint-color` function with the parameters `$background` and `$btn-hover-bg-tint-amount`.

So, there are three SASS variables you need to control to affect the Bootstrap button background color on hover:

1. `$background`
2. `$btn-hover-bg-shade-amount`
3. `$btn-hover-bg-tint-amount`